# Can't get 'at' to run a script under linux

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am having problems getting the 'at' command to run a script file:
This one works fine:

```
[myid@els-e37620 init.d]$ at now + 2 min
at> echo "this is my test" | write myid >/dev/null 2>&1
at> <EOT>
job 20 at Thu Jan 30 17:26:00 2014
```

But nothing happens when I try to run my script with 'at':

```
[myid@els-e37620 init.d]$ at now + 2 min
at> ./users/myid/bashtest.sh
at> <EOT>
job 21 at Thu Jan 30 17:31:00 2014
```

As far as I have seen the job is added to the 'at' queue and removed after the designated time but nothing happens! Is it executed somewhere else?

Thanks very much

Comment: Have you tried specifying an absolute path to your script?

Comment: `at` is supposed to remember the working directory, so a relative path should work.

Comment: What's in `bashtest.sh`? Try adding `exec > /tmp/at.log 2>&1` at the top of the `at` script to log all output `/tmp/at.log`.

Comment: Run your job with `env -i ./users/myid/bashtest.sh` and see if it still works or if it's relying on something in your environment.

Comment: Are you sure the path to the script is correct? It looks like it's an absolute path from the root directory, but you prefixed it with `.`, so it will be found relative to your current directory.

Comment: @thatotherguy `at` is also supposed to copy the environment, except for terminal-specific variables.

Comment: Thank you all, to answer to you comments:

Answer (score 0):

The `at` command is usually disabled due to possible security issues. In the old days, it was possible to set an `at` job, then go into the queue and change the script including the environment before the job started.

One of the things you need to look at are the `at.allow` and `at.deny` files. These are sometimes kept under the `/etc` directory, sometimes under `/var` and sometimes under `/usr/lib/cron`.  You'll need to look in your at manpage to find the actual location. If there's an empty `at.allow` file, then you cannot run any at jobs.

Another thing you should look at the manpage of your `atrun` command. The `atrun` command is what executes the `at` jobs. On some systems, the `atrun` command must be setup in the root's crontab file. On Macs, it's run by the `launchd` daemon, and you must run the `launchctl` command to start the `atrun` process.

Comment: @ David W. As I mentioned the first job which is just an echo command works fine so I don't think there is any issue with 'at' not running, or is there?

Comment: @ David W. there is an at.deny file that I don't have permission to open, and there is no at.allow; I tried to make one but it didn't allow me either. But if 'at' is not allowed to run, how does my first example run?

Comment: @user3255590 When you setup an At job, it usually creates a shell script in the At queue waiting for execution. You may want to take a look at that shell script, and see if you can run it as a shell script. That might give you an idea where the issue could be.

Comment: @ David W. I found the script in the 'at' queue with at -c <at job number> and copy/pasted into a file in the same directory of the script and ran after making executable > it worked fine - displayed the echo text!

Comment: @user3255590 Displayed the echo text? You have no console on an `at` command. There's no place for text to echo. STDOUT and STDERR are mailed to the user via `sendmail`, but if `sendmail` isn't setup, you won't get any mail, and even if `sendmail` is running, you will get it via the user's mailbox and not your normal mailbox (unless you've really setup sendmail). Check `/var/spool/mail` or `/var/mail` and see if you have mail.